# show hide field depend on select value sharepoint online

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have a list of 2 columns, the first one is "City" which is choice type.the second column is "Other" which is a single line of text.
when the user chooses "other " in City I want "OtherCity "column appears, if he chooses another choice, I want to hide.
I write the code using simple javascript, I do not want to use any library just simple code in javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function mySelectfunction(){
  getValue = document.getElementById("City").value;
  if(getValue == "other"){                     
    document.getElementById("OtherCity").style.display ="none";
  }else{                   
    document.getElementById("OtherCity").style.display ="block";
  }
}
 </script>
```

but it does not work. can you help make it work?
*another question: if the second column which I want to hide type is "lookup " will the code be different?

Comment: Post your html as well :)

Comment: it is out of box list , how can I get its HTML code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My test code for your reference,and Choice and lookup column do not need to change the code.

Add a script editor in NewForm,and insert the code into it(replace the column name).

```
 <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/SiteAssets/sputility.js">

</script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Get a single select dropdown field
        var relacionField = SPUtility.GetSPField('CityLookUp');

        // create a function to show or hide Rates based on Rate value
        var showOrHideField = function() {
            var relacionFieldValue = relacionField.GetValue();
            // Hide the Rates field if the selected value is Especial
            if(relacionFieldValue === 'other') {
                SPUtility.ShowSPField('Other')
            }
            else {
                SPUtility.HideSPField('Other')
            }
        };

        // run at startup (for edit form)
        showOrHideField();

        // make sure if the user changes the value we handle it
        $(relacionField.Dropdown).on('change', showOrHideField);
    });

    </script>
```

You can download sputility.js  here: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=sputility

**Updated:**

Did the code above report any error?

JavaScript code:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(show,"sp.js");
  function show () {
  //Get the select element corresponding to column
    var selectElement=document.getElementById('CityLookUp').parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[3].childNodes[3].childNodes[0];//chnage coulmn name
    //get tr the hidden column located
    var trElement=document.getElementById('Other').parentNode.parentNode;//change column name 
    //hide tr when we get into page,if the default value is 'other' ,do not need this
    trElement.style.display='none';
    //select change event 
    selectElement.onchange =  function () {
     var index = selectElement.selectedIndex;
     //get option value
    var value = selectElement.options[index].text;

      if(value==='other'){
      //show  tr element
        trElement.style.display='';
      }else{
      //hide  tr element
        trElement.style.display='none';
      }
    }
  }
```

The code idea is to find the corresponding select element and decide whether to hide the tr element where column other is located according to the value of option.

**Tip:** Our page dom structure may be different, so you may need to modify the code according to your page dom structure. You could view your page dom structure by Developer tool.
Test result:
[image: test result]

Comment: i want to use a simple javascript code without using library

Comment: it is working.can you please add a comment so I can understand each command for what..why you choose node?

Comment: is there sth wrong with the code that I wrote.?is the code that you provided is the only way to solve the issue. can you please suggest a course for me to learn how to write such a code   @Amos_MSFT

Comment: You could learn more about javaScriot.https://www.w3schools.com/js/

Comment: I took a basic course in javascript.  I am still learning javascript. I wrote the code it worked fine outside a SharePoint. but not doing anything in SharePoint. what is the next course to study? why is my code not working?

Comment: The difference of Dom structure will affect the running result of the code.Please mark as answer if it helped you.

Comment: can you recommend a course for me after I finished from the javascript course?